# Class not found error, using autoload to use class

Tags: php, autoload

Am getting error :

> Class 'location' not found in C:\wamp\www\New folder\index.php on
>   line....

Project File Location : http://localhost/New%20folder/
here both class file and index file is saved.

Class File: **location.class.php**

```
class location
{
    function add_location()
    {
        echo 'Its working!';
    }
}
```

My Code (**index.php** file in root directory)

```
<?php
function __autoload($class_name) {
      if (file_exists($class_name . '.class.php')) 
      {
          require_once ($class_name . '.class.php');
      }   
}
try {
    $location = new location();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Autoload Testing</title>
    </head>    
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i tried same code and its working. What version of php you are using?

Comment: PHP Version : 5.5.12

Comment: I'm using 5.5.11 and it's working fine.

Comment: Oh... i tryd too many times.. but its not working.

Comment: autoload function actually get the file... i use file_exist to check the file if it exists in that particular directory. I also use else block for it...

Comment: Works flawless when I add <?php ... ?> around your code for location.class.php

Comment: try using this method instead http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Comment: ohh...! WTF!!! I forgot php open and closing tags..... Yeah not its working.... thaks @maxhb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed the opening php tag in location.class.php.

```
<?php

class location
{
    function add_location()
    {
        echo 'Its working!';
    }
}
```

(Closing tag `?>` is optional at the end of file.)

Answer (score 0):

change your location.class.php content as following..

```
  



//php opening
function __autoload($class_name) {



      if (file_exists( dirname( __FILE__ ).'/'.$class_name . '.class.php')) 
      {
          require_once (dirname( __FILE__ ).'/'.$class_name . '.class.php');
      }   



}    
//php closing
```